# CouchDB 1.0.2 http_post_data on View from PHP Pecl Error Bad Content Type

Tags: php, couchdb, pecl

First, here is what my current system looks like:

- CouchDB 1.0.2
- PHP 5.3.6
- Apache httpd 2.2.19
- PECL http 1.7.1
- CouchDB-Lucene 0.6.1

I am building a mini search engine with CouchDB and CouchDB-Lucene. When the user enters a query I POST to my PHP script which then queries couchdb-lucene. Couchdb-lucene will then return a list of matching document keys to the PHP script. Then, I POST data (with http_post_data) to a List Function with that list of keys ([detailed here](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API), under "Querying Options"). This List Function returns HTML formatted results. This is the part that works.

My needs are now changing and I would like to query only the view and get back JSON. However, when I do, this is the response from the http_post_data call:

`HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
Server: CouchDB/1.0.2 (Erlang OTP/R13B)
Date: Sat, 09 Jul 2011 22:22:51 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 78
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
{"error":"bad_content_type","reason":"Content-Type must be application/json"}`

The URL that I generate for this view is correct. I can change my POST call to

`http_post_data(url/of/view, $key_string, "Content-Type:application/json");`

but nothing will actually be returned (I am looking at output in Firebug). To send back my results, here is the relevant PHP:

`HttpResponse::setContentType("application/json");
HttpResponse::setData($response);`

`$response` contains the response from the http_post_data call to CouchDB.

Any suggestions? This has been driving me mad for a day and a bit now.

Thanks.

Comment: I think I might be missing something, but isn't `http_post_data` supposed to receive an assoc array (not a string) for options? If so, you should use `array('headers' => array('content-type' => 'application/json'))` instead of `"Content-Type:application/json"`

Comment: Well, that indeed was the problem. I had tried using the associative array `array("Content-Type" => "application/json")` but obviously I forgot to wrap it in the header. Here is the [link to the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-post-data.php) that details http_post_data. If you reply to the question I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`http_post_data` supposed to receive an assoc array (not a string) for options.

You should use `array('headers' => array('content-type' => 'application/json'))` instead of `"Content-Type:application/json"`